# Can one buy clothes during the 9 days if they will arrive after the 9 days?

Tags: halacha, clothing, internet, transactions, nine-days

In the past a person purchased clothing in-person, however nowadays many purchases are made online and are then shipped. I would like to know if any poskim discuss purchasing clothing during the nine days (which a person generally [should refrain from](https://dinonline.org/2011/07/24/buying-clothes-in-the-nine-days/)) online when the purchaser knows that the clothing will not arrive until after the 9 days.

Perhaps there is a difference between purchasing and physically retaining something even if it is not worn (and thereby having the pleasure of owning it and having it immediately accessible) versus purchasing and not having the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](https://dinonline.org/2011/07/24/buying-clothes-in-the-nine-days/).

While the question from there asks if one can buy new clothes during the 9 days even if he won't wear it until after that period, your question is a "subset" of that one. (I.e., if it won't be delivered until after the 9 days, you, obviously couldn't wear it until after then.)

In summary, no, one cannot purchase it unless it will not be available anymore or it will cost more afterwards.

In viewing O.C. 551:7, Mishnah Berurah #49, supports this idea, as well. The prohibition is simply on buying the item itself. I'm inferring that it doesn't matter if the item is in his possession or not. The prohibition seems to be the act of buying, itself with the knowledge that he will wear it afterwards. (I would assume that the same prohibition would apply if he were buying this as a gift for another Jew whom he would give the clothes to after Tish'a B'Av.) There is probably inherent pleasure in buying new clothes, regardless of when you will get them.

Comment: I have seen questions like this before, I believe mine is different because the person does not even experience the joy of having the item in her hands.

Comment: @rikitikitembo many people enjoy the actual act of shopping. Even online. Even if they don't buy anything. (I know I do)