# Can one order clothing before the 9 days if it will be delivered during the 9 days?

Tags: halacha, nine-days

Of course, the clothing would not be worn until after the 9 days.

Comment: See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84505/can-one-buy-clothes-during-the-9-days-if-they-will-arrive-after-the-9-days) and [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/buying-clothing-during-the-three-weeks-and-nine-days/) for the inverse scenario.